# Combining and separating sums

Tags: simplifying-expressions

How can I combine or separate sums in *Mathematica* in the way that `Together` or `Expand` work for rational expressions？

For example, how does one transform from

$$\text{Sum}\left[\frac{a}{\sqrt{n!}},\{n,0,\infty \}\right]+\text{Sum}\left[\frac{b}{\sqrt{n!}},\{n,0,\infty \}\right]$$

to

$$\text{Sum}\left[\frac{a+b}{\sqrt{n!}},\{n,0,\infty \}\right]$$

and vise versa?

Comment: This feels like a duplicate.  Does anyone recall an earlier question like this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If we don't mind using rules to merge the sums, here's one that can handle prefactors, different variables and limits (assuming the upper limits are always infinite):

```
mergesums = (ca_. Sum[a_, an_] + cb_. Sum[b_, bn_]) :> 
  With[{sum = Simplify[
       ca a + (cb b /. bn[[1]] -> an[[1]] + bn[[2]] - an[[2]])]}, 
    Sum[sum, an]] /; an[[3]] == bn[[3]] == \[Infinity]

(Sum[a/Sqrt[m!], {m, 0, \[Infinity]}] + 
   2 Sum[b/Sqrt[(n - 1)!], {n, 1, \[Infinity]}]) //. mergesums
(* Sum[(a + 2*b)/Sqrt[m!], {m, 0, Infinity}] *)
```

Answer (score 5):

This solution works for combining any number of separate sums:

```
Sum[a/Sqrt[n!], {n, 0, Infinity}] + 
Sum[b/Sqrt[n!], {n, 0, Infinity}] + 
Sum[c/Sqrt[n!], {n, 0, Infinity}] //. Sum[x_, z_] + Sum[y_, z_] :> Sum[Simplify[x + y], z]

(*outputs: Sum[(a + b + c)/Sqrt[n!], {n, 0, Infinity}]*)
```

Here, we apply a rule to combine two sums together. The `ReplaceRepeated` (`//.`) is used to apply the combination rule as long as there are separate sums left. Note that in the present form, my solution only works if the summation variable (here `n`) is the same in all the sums.

And here is how to separate the sums:

```
Sum[(a + b + c)/Sqrt[n!], {n, 0, Infinity}] /. Sum[x_, y_] :> (Sum[#, y] & /@ Expand@x)

(*outputs: Sum[a/Sqrt[n!], {n, 0, Infinity}] + 
           Sum[b/Sqrt[n!], {n, 0, Infinity}] + 
           Sum[c/Sqrt[n!], {n, 0, Infinity}]*)
```