# Collapsing summation

Tags: functions, summation

I am trying to write a command to collapse the sum of terms into an expression with summation. Something like

```
F_[1, j___] + F_[2, j___] + F_[3, j___] := Sum[F[i, j], {i, 1, 3}]
```

which is designed to to collapse the LHS, which is a function of 2 or more parameters (for example - F[i,j] or F[i,j,k] - this is the reason for the i___ in the definition) into a summation on the first variable. but I get the following error:

```
SetDelayed::write: "Tag Plus in F_[1,i___]+F_[2,i___]+F_[3,i___] is Protected"
```

It seems that I am overriding the *Plus* definition. I don't know then how to define this properly.
Thanks.

Comment: Do you want this to work for any head (hence `F_`) or only certain symbols?

Comment: In addition to the question @mfvonh asked, you should also specify what to do with cases like `F[1,i]+F[2,i]+F[3,i]` where `i` would appear as the summation index *and* as an external variable. That doesn't look like a replacement I would want to make in general. The answer would probably use `UpSetDelayed`, not unprotecting `Plus`.

Comment: Related: [(20540)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/20540)

Answer (score 1):

Plus is protected. but you can use unprotect.

```
Unprotect[Plus];
F_[1, j___] + F_[2, j___] + F_[3, j___] := 
 Defer@Sum[F[i, j], {i, 1, 3}]
Protect[Plus];
```

Comment: Will that change the definition of "Plus" forever?

Comment: Just it's effect in after run this code

Answer (score 1):

I think you may find value in this rule:

```
sequentialQ[x_List] := x == Range[x[[1]], x[[-1]]]

rule =
  HoldPattern[Plus[s : F_[_, j___] ..]] /; 
    sequentialQ @ {s}[[All, 1]] :>
      (HoldForm[Sum[F[i, j], {i, ##}]] & @@ {Min@#, Max@#} &[{s}[[All, 1]]]);
```

Test:

```
F[1.0, q, r] + F[1.5, q, r] + F[2, q, r] + F[2.7, q, r] + F[3.0, q, r] /. rule
```

[image]